# IOS Objc how to properly load UICollectionViewCell after Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, uicollectionview

i'm pretty new in obj/Xcode, and i need to do a `UIcollectionView` how take images from url request.
I've try to catch the scroll event with `scrollViewDidScroll`, then call the my request function with the parameter page + 1 or -1; depending of the scroll.

But everytime i'm going on infinite loop, and my cell images donc stop loading, i think its because my way is wrong :

Catching the scroll action :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
     [self reload];   
}
```

The function reload send the request and set the imgs.
How can i load properly the pages, and not 1000times for every scrolling.
Sorry for my english, and thank you

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call reload like that.  As you scroll, 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' is automatically called.  If theres a previously used cell in the table (out of view) then the cell is re-used for the new position it is populating - hence 'dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier' (hope you're using that?!).

So what you need to do is have code on that method itself, that will automatically 'lazy load' the image you want. Heres a copy of a cellForItemOfIndexPath method that achieves just that - the image is populated when its downloaded.

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

VideoSearchCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

YoutubeSearchResult *cellSearchResult = [self.ytSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (cellSearchResult.thumbnailImage.image == nil)
{
    //NSLog(@"loading image");
    __weak VideoSearchCell *weakCell = cell;
    __weak YoutubeSearchResult *weakResult = cellSearchResult;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:cellSearchResult.thumbUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_placeholder"];
    [cellSearchResult.thumbnailImage setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
     {
         weakResult.thumbnailImage.image = image;
         weakCell.imageView.image = image;
         [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
     } failure:nil];

} else {
    if (cell.imageView.image != cellSearchResult.thumbnailImage.image)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = cellSearchResult.thumbnailImage.image;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

So to explain - VideoSearchCell is my custom cell type.  Its fairly simple, it just has a UIImageView on it called 'imageView'.  Ive also got an array called 'ytSearchResults' - this contains an array of objects and some contain images, and some dont.  As the images download, the results also get populated to that array so I dont download them more than necessary.

The code checks to see if theres an image in that array.  If not, it does the downloading code.

By the way, I use __weak references to properties, because of ARC and not wanting to accidentally retain the cell, or the search result.  Not enough time to explain all that here though!  Hope the code helps.

One more thing - setImageWithURLRequest is a method from the very handy and extremely popular library AFNetworking (2.0).  Get hold of that as you will use it all the time.

Comment: What a fast answer, than you a lot Luke, i'll try that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to load images before cell is actually used, because you never know if user will see that cell. You can start image loading when 
`- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called, and before starting download request you must check if download of this image is in progress, otherwise you will load it more than once.